# Is there a security concern if the android:exported attribute of androidx.activity.ComponentActivity in the AndroidManifest is set to true?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Android Studio Build: 2022.3.1 Patch 1

Kotlin version: 1.7.20

Hello! I'd like to ask if today, in the build/intermediates/merged_manifest/debug/AndroidManifest.xml file, the following entry:

```
    <activity
    android:name="androidx.activity.ComponentActivity"
    android:exported="true"    />
```

has been flagged by SonarQube as a security concern, suggesting to "Implement permissions on this exported component." However, it seems like this was added through some plugins in Gradle. How can I change its exported attribute to false? Or does this configuration not affect the app's security, so I don't need to modify it?

The project in the attachment is my current gradle file, thank you for your help!

Android Studio Build: 2022.3.1 Patch 1

Kotlin version: 1.7.20

Below is my gradle file

```
    plugins {
        id 'com.android.application'
        id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
        id 'kotlin-kapt'
    }

android {
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.test.appbuild'
        minSdk 29
        //noinspection ExpiredTargetSdkVersion
        targetSdk 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        ndk{
            abiFilters "arm64-v8a", 'x86_64'
        }
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                abiFilters 'arm64-v8a', 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
                arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++-shared"
            }
        }
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField "String", "BACKEND_MODE", "\"123\""
            buildConfigField "String", "FUNCTION_LEVEL", "\"456\""
            buildConfigField "String", "ppp", "\"123456\""
            buildConfigField "boolean", "ENGMode", "true"
        }
        release {
            buildConfigField "String", "BACKEND_MODE", "\"123\""
            buildConfigField "String", "ppp", "\"123456\""
            buildConfigField "boolean", "ENGMode", "false"
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
        dataBinding true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.0'
    }
    ndkVersion '23.1.7779620'
    buildToolsVersion '33.0.2'
    compileSdk 34
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
    viewBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1"
        force 'androidx.core:core:1.10.1'

    }
}
dependencies {
//    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.6.0'  
//    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0' 

    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00')
    androidTestImplementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00')
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material'
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended") 
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview'
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest'
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material-icons-core")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3-window-size-class")
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.2'
    // Optional - Integration with ViewModels
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.6.1")
    // Optional - Integration with LiveData
    implementation("androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata")
    // Optional - Integration with RxJava
    implementation("androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-rxjava2")
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.0'
    implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.4.0")

    //debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.9.1'

    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.5.2'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:4.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
    implementation project(path: ':sdk')
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.2.0'

    implementation project(path: ':OcrLibrary')
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.2'
    implementation 'androidx.databinding:databinding-runtime:8.2.0'
    // implementation files('src/main/jniLibs/opencv-470.jar')
    // implementation project(':openCVLibrary470');
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    implementation 'com.blankj:utilcodex:1.31.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.1"



    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.1"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.4.1"
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.8'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.5.2"
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.3.0'
//    implementation 'com.github.jkcclemens:khttp:0.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.2' 
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi:5.1.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.1.0'
    // Amplify core dependency
    implementation 'com.amplifyframework:core:2.14.1'
    implementation 'com.amplifyframework:aws-api:2.14.1'
//    implementation 'com.amplifyframework:aws-datastore:2.14.1'
    implementation 'com.amplifyframework.ui:authenticator:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.amplifyframework:aws-storage-s3:2.14.1'
    implementation 'com.amplifyframework:aws-auth-cognito:2.14.1'
    // Support for Java 8 features
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.5'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.runtime:runtime:1.4.0'

    implementation 'com.amplifyframework:core-kotlin:2.14.2'

    // Camera
    def camerax_version = "1.3.0"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:${camerax_version}"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:${camerax_version}"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:${camerax_version}"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:${camerax_version}"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-video:${camerax_version}"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-extensions:${camerax_version}"
    implementation 'net.lingala.zip4j:zip4j:2.8.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.udojava:EvalEx:2.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.2' 
}
```

I have currently tried adding the following directly in the app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <activity
    android:name="androidx.activity.ComponentActivity"
    android:exported="false" />
```

However, this causes an error when building the APK.

Directly modifying build/intermediates/merged_manifest/debug/AndroidManifest.xml will revert the changes back to:

```
    <activity
    android:name="androidx.activity.ComponentActivity"
    android:exported="true" />
```

after rebuilding.

Could this issue potentially lead to security concerns? Currently, there is an activity like the following:

```
    import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
    class LoginActivity : ComponentActivity() {
        ... my code....
    }
```

Comment: I later discovered that when I was deploying, I used the process build -> build bundle -> build apk for deploying the apk, which resulted in the deployed version being a debug version. Later on, when using the formal Release method, build -> generate signed bundle for constructing the apk, after deployment, the "androidx.activity.ComponentActivity" android:exported="true" entry was no longer present in app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\release\androidmanifest.xml. Furthermore, upon investigation, the released apk adopts that androidmanifest.xml file as the basis for the final version.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this would be added to your manifest, but I think it's safe to ignore it.

When you export an activity (to allow it to be used by other app) you need to specify the `intent-filter` block in the manifest to define how external apps can interact with it.

Comment: That's not entirely true.  If an Activity is exported, you can launch it by name directly from another app, without an intent filter.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I later found out that my problem was due to a mistake in the build process, which has now been resolved. I have documented the process in the my command section.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want external apps to be able to directly launch that Activity?  If not, then it should not be exported.  If yes, then it should be exported.  Note that the launcher Activity must be exported, as must any activities that are used with intent filters.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I later found out that my problem was due to a mistake in the build process, which has now been resolved. I have documented the process in the my command section